# Api de Cargos e Funções

Tags: api

Por acaso existe alguma API, que liste cargos e funções de empregos?(No brasil)
Exemplo: `Informática -> DBA, Programador, Suporte Técnico.`
Entre outros tipos de empregos.
Não precisa necessariamente ser uma API, pode ser tipo algum arquivo ao qual consiga importa em meu banco de dados.

Comment: Olá Max. Se você deseja uma lista e todos os empregos reconhecidos no Brasil ou em Portugal, sugiro adicionar essa informação na pergunta.

Comment: Cara na verdade, só queria uma lista de empregos (no Brasil), de preferência que fosse separado por categorias. Igual ao exemplo: Informática é a categoria, e dentro de informática teria o DBA, Programador e etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Brasil existe a [Classificação Brasileira de Ocupações](http://www.mtecbo.gov.br/cbosite/pages/home.jsf).

Você pode baixar os arquivos CSV com os dados para importar na sua aplicação no link:

http://www.mtecbo.gov.br/cbosite/pages/downloads.jsf

Comment: Acabei de encontrar esse link kk.Não sei pq negativaram sua resposta se ela se encaixa na pergunta. Mas conheceria algo que fosse separado por categoria? Caso não encontre marco sua resposta como aceita.

Comment: API mesmo não conheço. Geralmente os dados que o governo disponibiliza são arquivos para download.